# How to get the search to work when the user presses enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the button Iv`e created and search bar that has a function to go to a page when a user clicks search tab but I need it to work when the user presses enter as well.

This is the search bar and button

```
<input type="text" method="get" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search" value="">
<button type="button" id="go" class="btn btn-default" onclick="sendToPage();">Search</button>
```

This is the function

```
function sendToPage(){
    var input = document.getElementById("search").value;

    //Check to see if the user has entered apple/iphone;
    if (input === "apple"){
        //location.href="apple.html";                    
        location.replace("apple.html");
        return false;
    }
    else if (input === "iphone"){
        location.replace("apple.html");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your button click code ? Or what is the button name ?

Answer (score 1):

Putting a form around the input should give you the result you're looking for. Then just add an "onsubmit" to the form that calls your sendToPage(); function.

Comment: I tried that and then the onclick function doesn`t work

Comment: @JadePage the onclick function of the button doesn't work with onsubmit in the form?

Comment: nothing works when I use the form and change onclick to onsubmit

Comment: @JadePage don't change onclick to onsubmit, put an onsubmit event in the form and leave the button as onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `keyup` and check its `event.keyCode`. If the key code is `13`, it means the user clicked enter while on the input text.

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("search")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if (input === "apple")              
            location.replace("apple.html");
        else if (input === "iphone")
            location.replace("apple.html");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Or using your function `sendToPage()`:

```
document.getElementById("search")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sendToPage();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Tried using that but then the form submits everytime i press a key down, When the user starts typing what they looking for it triggers the event and the search function doesn`t run

Answer (score 0):

It seems the id of your input field is 'search' so you can try this:
note that the keycode of enter is 13. so we can compare the input codes with 13. if its true then do the search.

```
$('#search').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       var input = $(this).val();
       if (input === "apple"){
            //location.href="apple.html";                    
              location.replace("apple.html");
              return false;
       }
       else if (input === "iphone"){
              location.replace("apple.html");
              return false;
       }
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Ankush that does make sense. I will try that example.

Comment: Iv`e tried all these examples but none of them work :(

Answer (score -1):

```
This is the button 

<!-This is the button -->
<div id="search-bar">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" method="get" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search" value="">
     <button type="button" id="go" class="btn btn-default" onclick="sendToPage();" onChange="aliasonclick">Search</button>
</div>
</div>
```